# Background color from XML

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have a layout and i want to set your background color with this xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#000000"></item>
<item android:color="#ffffff" ></item>
</selector>
```

this layout to be in a tabhost and where is selected it change your olor, how I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's three "main" states you need to take into account: selected, pressed and the rest. Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/tab_background_active" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/tab_background_pressed"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_inactive" />
</selector>
```

You should also use "focused" if you care about supporting users with trackballs.